# How to use validators in Strict Types of Pydantic like StrictStr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, validation, pydantic

Currently I have schema with field "name". I use `constr` to specify it

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    name: constr(strict=True, min_length=1, max_length=50)
```

I want to use pydantic StrictStr type like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr, Field

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    name: StrictStr = Field(min_length=1, max_length=50)
```

But it raises error:

```
E   ValueError: On field "name" the following field constraints are set but not enforced: max_length, min_length.
E   For more details see https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#unenforced-field-constraints
```

In docs, as i understand, it advices to use use raw attribute name like `maxLength` isntead of `max_length`(like `exclusiveMaximum` for int) but this constraints are not enforced so validations are not applied.

My question is: How I can use `StrictStr` type for name field and apply native validations like `min_length`, `max_length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options here, either you create a new type based on StrictString, or you inherit from StrictString or you use constr with strict set to True. Creating a type as done below does the same as inheriting from StrictString, just a different syntax if you want. That should all give you the necessary type validations. In code, that would read like

```py
MyStrictStr1 = type('MyStrictStr', (StrictStr,), {"min_length":1, "max_length":5})


class MyStrictStr2(StrictStr):
    min_length = 1
    max_length = 5

MyStrictStr3 = constr(min_length=1, max_length=5, strict=True)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I can not use Field() with validators for StrictStr? So i have to create my own stricttype to use validations?

Comment: yes, that's the way it is